# Mongoose: How to create a document and simultaneously push a sub array into it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I am trying to seed a mongo database with users and the users friends.

Users is it's own Model (with a ref to the Friends model).

I have two arrays of data to use to seed the database. 
The friends array contains sub arrays. Each subarray –in order– contains the friends for the respective user array. *i.e friends[0] are the friends for user[0].*

The goal is to create the user, then search to determine if the users friends document exist all-ready. If they don't, create the friend document, and push them to that user.

The code creates the users, but only creates the friends from the friends[0]. It seems to do with async, but have not idea where to go next.

```
   function doSomething(){
        var i = 0;
        userArray.forEach(function(user){
            User.create(user, function(err, createdUser){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
                console.log(createdUser.name + ' created!');
                var incrementer = 0;
                for(let friend of friends[i]){
                    Friend.find({name: friend.name}, function(foundFriend){
                        if(foundFriend == undefined){
                            Friend.create(friend, function(err, createdFriend){
                                createdUser.friends.push(createdFriend);
                                createdUser.save;
                                console.log(createdFriend.name + ' added to' + createdUser.name + ' friends!');
                                incrementer++;
                                if(incrementer === friends[i].length){
                                        i++; 
                                    }                                        
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }

    //Output I would expect (assuming no documents exist)

    //John Smith created!
    //Sally added to John Smith friends
    //Mike added to John Smith friends

    //Mary Doe created!
    //Bob added to Mary Doe friends!
    //Gary added to Mary Doe friends!

    //Instead I am getting (assuming no matching documents exist)

    //John Smith created!
    //Mary Doe created!


    //Sally added to John Smith friends!
    //Sally added to Mary Doe friends!
    //Mike added to Mary Doe friends!
    //Sally added to Mary Doe friends!
```

This last part of output is random and changes with each run.

Answer (score 0):

I would split your loop into two separate tasks. P.S. Consider to save not `user.friends` but `user.friendsIDs` (its more common)

```js
var users = [
  {name: 'user 1'}, 
  {name: 'user 2'}
];

var friends = [
  [{name: 'Alex'}, {name: 'John'}],
  [{name: 'Alex'}, {name: 'Max'}]
];



// save all friends first
var flattenFriends = [].concat.apply([], friends);

var names = [];

var filteredFriends = flattenFriends.filter(function(friend, i) {
  if(names.indexOf(friend.name) > -1) return false;
  names.push(friend.name);
  return true;
});

filteredFriends.forEach(function(friend) {
  
  Friend.find({name: friend.name}, function(found) {
    if(!found) {
      var newFriend = new Friend(friend);
      newFriend.save();
    }
  });
  
});

// save all users (with friends)
users.forEach(function(user, i) {
  
  var user = user;
  user.friends = [];
  
  friends[i].forEach(function(friend, j) {
    Friend.find({name: friend.name}, function(found) {
      user.friends.push(found)
    })
  });
  
  var newUser = new User(user);
  newUser.save();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much closer to what I want, except it is creating a friend that all ready exists. In your example Alex is getting created twice. In other words, Alex is a friend to bother users, but should only be created on the first iteration. The `Friend.find`, is not finding Alex after the first/initial creation, and thus creating another document of Alex. Also I had to change `!found to found==null`, as that is what `Friend.find` is returning. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, that's because async save() function. We could filter (reject duplicate) friends before saving (I've edited my code)